# In build Function<T,R> right practice implement inside interface?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I have a question where I expect to know what is right practice. code I am adding here just example. so may not any rationality.

I am going to use Function in build functional interface. my method look like this

```
    Function<List<Manager>, List<Employee>> getEmployeesFromManager = m -> {

       List<Employee> emps = new LinkedList<>();
       for (Manager mgr : m) {
         Employee emp=new Employee();
         //do stuff
         emps.add(emp);
}

    return questActionParameters;
};
```

My Question is this. I can add this code inside interface and also I can add this code inside of service Impl class. (Springboot application). considering thread safe and  best practice what is the right place to this code? Interface or class?

Comment: Generally, if its an implementation, as this appears to be, I would put it in a class.  You can create an interface and make this an implementation.  Putting this in an interface as a default method put it at the lowest priority for execution.  Meaning an abstract class that has this same signature will never call this code.

Comment: @MaxPower " Meaning an abstract class that has this same signature will never call this code. " Good point. but your other point. just because its an implementation shouldn't put in to a class right? because with Java 8 it ask us to put implementations to an interface also with `default` method

Comment: I would argue (and again, doesn't mean I am right) just because you can, doesn't mean you should.  In my opinion a default method is great for an already existing interface, and you want to add additional methods to it without breaking anyone else's code that is currently using the interface.  For example see `forEach` on the `List` interface

Comment: also, since you tagged this as functional-interface, a default method cannot be called via a lambda.  If one of your goals is to allow lambda's to call this, it cannot be a default method.